# android, unknown host exception

Tags: android, web-services, dns, host

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to solve UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903644/how-to-solve-unknownhostexception)

I get `Unknown Host` exception when trying to query the server on the emulator. I have been working on this for a week, so:

- I have Internet permission in the manifest.
- The emulator has Internet access, I can go to Google and navigate.
- The firewall sf off.
- I set up the server and ip name in both, the hosts of machine and the hosts of the emulator.
- I tried to turn Wi-Fi on the emulator on and off.
- I tried to restart the emulator.
- I tried to delete the AVD and create a new one. Did not work.
- Restarting the computer also does not do anything.
- Web service's USL that return JSON data works in the web browser but not in the emulator.
- I tried to create a new project, just to prove the JSON reading from the server and got the same error.

Any suggestion?

This is the code:

```
public class OrderRequestParser{

public static final String url = "http://srvsapqas.mejiarcala.com:8000/sap(bD1lcyZjPTYwMA==)/bc/bsp/sap/zsilm_not/consultarbuzon.htm?FILTRO=USUARIO&PATRON=CESTEVEZ#";
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private HttpGet del;

public List<OrderRequest> listOrderRequest()
    {

try {


            del = new HttpGet(urlSevicioCarlo);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(del);
            String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

            Log.e("d", respStr)
}
...
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: "_I get Unknown Host exception when trying to query the server on the emulator_" What do you mean "the server"? What server?

Comment: If the server is in your development machine(localhost), use ip address 10.0.2.2  refer to https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: I had edited to add the code. I mean, when I try to get information in json from the web service, then I get the error.

Comment: It;s not in the localhost. It's a web service. So, I dont need to use the port that the emuladtor accepts.